# Incompatibility between `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` and `tkz` macros `\tkzRep` and `\tkzDrawLine`

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, tkz-euclide, tkz-base

In the MWE below, unless `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` is loaded `pic ["$\alpha$",draw, fill=yellow]{angle= A--B--C}` in picture (1) flags compile ERROR `!Missing \endcsname inserted`. However, with `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` loaded `\tkzRep[color=red, ynorm=2]` in picture (2) and `\tkzDrawLine(A,B)` in picture (3) both flag compile ERROR `!Undefined control sequence.\tkz`. Curiously, all other `\tkz` macros seem to work fine, for example `\tkzDrawPoints`, `\tkzDrawSegment` etc. Is there an escape from this dilemma?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 20 October 2017
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,ngerman,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
  (1) Till Tantau:\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (3,0) coordinate (A)
    -- (0,1) coordinate (B)
    -- (1,2) coordinate (C)
    pic ["$\alpha$",draw, fill=yellow]{angle= A--B--C}
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}

  (2) Alain Matthes: tkz-base\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{xaxe style/.style={-}}
    \tikzset{yaxe style/.style={-}}
    \tkzInit[xmax=4,ymax=4]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzDrawX  
    \tkzDrawY
%    \tkzRep[color=red, ynorm=2]
  \end{tikzpicture}

  (3) Alain Matthes: tkz-euclide\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
    \tkzDefShiftPointCoord[2,3](30:4){B}
    \tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,B=2)
    \tkzGetPoint{I}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,I)
%    \tkzDrawLine(A,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,I)
  \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the `babel` library does is no more than

```
\tikzset{
  handle active characters in code,
  handle active characters in nodes
}
```

And what it does is change the character code of various characters back to their default. I can't give you exact details, but seeing as the error says

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \tkz
        @Rep@ylabel
```

it seems that a macro `\tkz@Rep@ylabel` is encountered in a place where the character code of `@` has been set to other (I'm guessing), so it cannot be used in a macro.

Anyways, you can work around the problem by locally setting `/tikz/handle active characters in nodes=false`

i.e.

```
\tkzRep[/tikz/handle active characters in nodes=false,color=red, ynorm=2]

\tkzDrawLine[/tikz/handle active characters in nodes=false](A,B)
```

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 20 October 2017
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,ngerman,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
  (1) Till Tantau:\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (3,0) coordinate (A)
    -- (0,1) coordinate (B)
    -- (1,2) coordinate (C)
    pic ["$\alpha$",draw, fill=yellow]{angle= A--B--C}
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}

  (2) Alain Matthes: tkz-base\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{xaxe style/.style={-}}
    \tikzset{yaxe style/.style={-}}
    \tkzInit[xmax=4,ymax=4]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzDrawX  
    \tkzDrawY
    \tkzRep[/tikz/handle active characters in nodes=false,color=red, ynorm=2]
  \end{tikzpicture}

  (3) Alain Matthes: tkz-euclide\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
    \tkzDefShiftPointCoord[2,3](30:4){B}
    \tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,B=2)
    \tkzGetPoint{I}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,I)
    \tkzDrawLine[/tikz/handle active characters in nodes=false](A,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,I)
  \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: It works, I'll mark it as an answer. And thanks for sparing me the "exact details", I would not have been able to understand them.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth Well, I don’t know the details myself ...

Comment: A final comment for the benefit of those who are interested: the problem addressed in the MWE  applies to macros `\tkzRep`, `\tkzDrawLine`, `\tkzDrawLines`, `\tkzDrawBisector`, `\tkzDrawMedian` and `\tkzDrawAltitude`. The answer provided by @Torbjørn is a fix for each.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth I rewrote the code of several macros and the problem disappeared in the next version