# Incompatibility between \usetikzlibrary{babel} and the tkz-graph \Edge macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, tkz-graph

Continuing on from my question posted yesterday, I struck a similar problem with the `\Edge` macro of `tkz-graph` when attempting to define text labels - with `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` loaded compile ERROR `!Undefined control sequence.\cmdGR` is flagged. The fix provided for the previous question, if applied here, raises `!Package xkeyval Error: '/tikz/handle active characters in nodes' undefined in families 'edge'`; as demonstrated for `\Edge[...](C)(B)`

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 21 October 2017
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,ngerman,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
%\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{Alain Matthes: tkz-graph}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\SetUpEdge[lw = 1.5pt,
color = orange,
labelcolor = gray!30,
labelstyle = {draw}]
\SetGraphUnit{3}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
\Vertex{P}
\NOEA(P){B}
\SOEA(P){M}
\SOEA(B){C}
%\Edge[/tikz/handle active characters in nodes=false,label=bc](C)(B)
\Edge[label=bp](B)(P)
\Edge[label=pm](P)(M)
\Edge[label=cm](C)(M)
\Edge[label=bm](B)(M)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than applying the fix of the other question ([Incompatibility between `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` and `tkz` macros `\tkzRep` and `\tkzDrawLine`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397171/15925)) to `\Edge`, you can put the edge commands within a scope where the fix is applied:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 21 October 2017
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,ngerman,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{Alain Matthes: tkz-graph}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\SetUpEdge[lw = 1.5pt,
color = orange,
labelcolor = gray!30,
labelstyle = {draw}]
\SetGraphUnit{3}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
\Vertex{P}
\NOEA(P){B}
\SOEA(P){M}
\SOEA(B){C}
\begin{scope}[/tikz/handle active characters in nodes=false]
\Edge[label=bc](C)(B)
\Edge[label=bp](B)(P)
\Edge[label=pm](P)(M)
\Edge[label=cm](C)(M)
\Edge[label=bm](B)(M)
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```